# Datastax OpsCenter default consistency level for collecting metrics from the nodes

Tags: cassandra, nosql, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I just want to know what consistency level using OpsCenter for collecting metrics from the nodes using datastax-agent ? as we know OpsCenter created a keyspace called opscenter in the database once we installed and started the process where we can see multiple rollups tables. Is there any configuration manually or it is defined in opscenter code statically? What if we have OpsCenter cluster configuration with failover?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataStax Agent writes collected metrics directly, not sending them to the OpsCenter itself, so it doesn't depend if OpsCenter itself is setup in failover mode, or not.

By default, agent should use LOCAL_ONE or ONE (don't remember), and it isn't configurable.  But you just need to remember that consistency level is how many nodes should confirm successful write - writes themselves are are sent to all replicas, so even if node that confirmed write crashed, then there is still a chance that data is written to other replicas.

Comment: Thanks Alex, bur how rollups tables write the data?